# Companion Class using variable from companion object , how to test method in companion class with scalatest

Tags: scala, apache-spark, mocking, scalatest, companion-object

I have an implementation like below, where I have some methods in a companion class that I am calling in the companion object. The methods in the companion class use some private variables from companion objects.

```
class Foo{

  def loadFinalDF(df:DataFrame): DataFrame ={
    val finaldf: DataFrame = df
      .withColumn("Date", lit(date)).distinct()
    finaldf
  }
}

object Foo {

  import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
  val spark = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()
  import spark.implicits._
  
  val someDF = Seq(
          (8, "bat"),
          (64, "mouse"),
          (-27, "horse")
          ).toDF("number", "word")

  val obj = new Foo
  private val date = "2019-03-01"
  val finalDF = obj.loadFinalDF(someDF)

}
```

I want to write test cases for loadFinalDF method, but I am not sure how can I do that with the date variable defined in the companion object. I am guessing I might have to use mock testing of some sort but I have never done mock testing before and online resources are very confusing to understand. How can I write a test case for this method? Please help!
Thank you!

Comment: You could pass the date as an optional parameter to the function. Then as default argument, you use the date from the companion object but in the tests you provide one yourself.

Comment: yes, that's an option. And I modified my code to make date a parameter. I was wondering though from a mock testing perspective, if it will be possible to mock values from the Foo object.